# How to pass datatype and use it in method with java?

Tags: java, types, return, arguments

EDIT:
Here's the methods i'm trying to get to work...

```
public static <T> void save(T t, Object o, String fileName)
{
        ObjectOutputStream out = 
                new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        out.writeObject((T)o);
        out.close();
}

public static <T> T load(T t, String fileName)
{
    T object = null;

    ObjectInputStream in = 
            new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(fileName));
    object = (T)in.readObject();
    in.close();

    return (T)object;
}
```

Save works when using the code below.

```
int test = 7;
save(int.class, test, "test.dat");
```

But with load() i cant get it to work.
The following doesn't work, i get "Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Class to int".

```
int test2 = load(int.class, "test.dat");
```

If i change it to what Eclipse suggest:

```
Class<Integer> test = method(int.class);
```

I get an exception instead: "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Class".

So how should i use T as a return type to get it to work?

Comment: Read the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) and google examples (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Comment: Q: What exactly do you want?  If you want to "write something generic" - then use Java 1.5++ "[Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)".  If you want to "reinvent" generics - then don't.  Consider what you can do with Java, or a Java-compatible scripting language like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/For+those+new+to+both+Java+and+Groovy)

Comment: Trinimom: Thanks, this helped me a bit. But i cant get it to work when using return.
FoggyDay: No i don't want to reinvent anything. And what i want is in the question is it not?

Comment: Can you show more of your new code - it is unclear what you have changed at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the general concern I'd have with the overall design, in terms of getting your actual code working, the real problem is that you don't need to pass int.class to the T variable - you need to pass the object you want to write.

So your code will work if you just change it to:

```
public static <T> void save(T t, String fileName)
{
        ObjectOutputStream out = 
                new ObjectOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        out.writeObject(t);
        out.close();
}

public static <T> T load(String fileName)
{
    T object = null;

    ObjectInputStream in = 
            new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(fileName));
    object = (T)in.readObject();
    in.close();

    return (T)object;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
    save(50, "C:\\test.dat");
    save("A String", "C:\\test2.dat");

    Integer t1 = load("C:\\test.dat");
    System.out.println(t1);

    String t2 = load("C:\\test2.dat");
    System.out.println(t2);
```

With that said, there are a number of questions with this approach. As you already know the type, the use of the T variable has practically zero value in this instance and you do not gain much from it.

If the type is wrong, then the cast will still fail at runtime. e.g. this code will still raise a `ClassCastException,` because the compiler knows you expect T to be an Integer, and will try to cast it to an Integer, but an actual String is loaded from the file.

```
    save("A String", "C:\\test2.dat");
    Integer t1 = load("C:\\test2.dat");
```

I am not sure how useful it actually is - but in terms of getting your code actually working, that should be fine.

Also, the code you supplied doesn't compile because the exceptions from the File Processing raises `IOException` which you neither catch nor declare to be thrown. I've not changed this.

Comment: I guess this is a better way of doing it then i tried to, so i'll run with this method. Thank you! Also i removed the try-catch from the code to just show the relevant stuff.